# Google Gadget Refreshing

Tags: google-gadget

I'm creating a test Google Gadget. Its a simple hello world gadget.  However, after I add the gadget to iGoogle the first time, any subsequent changes I make to the file on my server have no effect on the gadget!  If I change the name of the xml file and then read it, then I see the change.  But no amount of changing, or deleting and re-adding the gadget will pick up any of my modifications on the server.  Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

http://www.google.com/ig/modules/developer.xml
add that gadget, then turn off the cacheing of your test gadget

Comment: Onces you have the developer.xml gadget on your iGoogle page as well as the gadget you are createing, you can untick the "cached" tick box next to the gadget you are actively editing. (identified by the gadget's xml filename)